# Coloured fonts no longer show in Terminal

Tags: command-line, fonts

Terminal always used to display different colours for directories, files etc. Recently it changed to show all items white against the normal purple background.
How do I get the colours back please?

Comment: Which terminal? The default Gnome Terminal uses profiles that you can edit. Every profile can be set to a colour palette, and if those don't suit you you can also set them manually. But there are many other "terminal emulation" programs.

Comment: probably the profile has been changed somehow. Open `~/.bashrc` and uncomment the line containing `#force_color_prompt=yes`, or edit the line that sets `PS1`

Comment: Tried 'ray@ray-Lenovo-V110-15IAP:~$ ~/.bashrc
bash: /home/ray/.bashrc: No such file or directory
ray@ray-Lenovo-V110-15IAP:~$ ~/.bashrc
bash: /home/ray/.bashrc: No such file or directory
ray@ray-Lenovo-V110-15IAP:~$ /.bashrc
bash: /.bashrc: No such file or directory  What  am I doing wrong?

Comment: Screenshot of gedit .bashrc. Is this the line? How do I uncomment it please?/home/ray/Desktop/Screenshot from 2020-03-22 11-36-09.png

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I must have 'stumbled upon' the solution for all has returned to technicolour normalcy!
Thanks to all who tried to help.